# How to understand Tarski’s Real Closed Field theory result

Tags: first-order-logic, real-numbers, model-theory, decidability

The decision problem I have is: the truth values of any First Order Logic sentences that contain arithmetic operations and equalities/inequalities on any real numbers.

Per Tarski’s Real Closed Field (RCF) theory result, does it mean the above decision problem is decidable?

If not, then in the above decision problem, is it decidable if I replace "any real numbers" with "a subset of real numbers that satisfy the following conditions" ?

The conditions are:
This real number subset includes constant 0 and 1 and satisfies the following 3 axioms:

1)the axioms of ordered fields

2)the axiom asserting that every positive number has a square root

3)for every odd number d, the axiom asserting that all polynomials of degree d have at least one root.

I know RCF does not necessarily mean real numbers, but I am trying to use RCF on real numbers.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. It seems your question is about whether the decidability of the theory of real closed fields applies to sentences which use arbitrary real numbers as parameters? Remember that decidability is about algorithms and computing - how do you propose to give arbitrary real numbers as input to the decision algorithm?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143727/7062) for a discussion of whether mere *equality* of two real numbers is decidable.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks.  I just edited my question and see if it's clear enough now?

Comment: The decision problem in the first paragraph is still not clear. If you allow arbitrary real numbers to appear in your sentences, then there are uncountably many possible inputs to your decision problem. But by the usual definition of "decision problem", there should only be countably many possible inputs. If you want to use a variant of the notion of decision problem that can accept infinitary inputs, you need to explain what definition you're using and how exactly the sentences will presented as inputs.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks for the clarification. Isn’t it true that RCF theory also allows uncoutably infinite inputs and yet it itself claims to be decidable?  For example: “Example 1F.14” in Page 29 of the UCLA lecture at https://www.math.ucla.edu/~ynm/lectures/lnl.pdf which shows the whole real set is in its universe.



On the other hand, we know not all real numbers are computable.  That confuses me how can RCF be decidable.

Comment: "RCF theory allows uncountably many inputs" doesn't make any sense. Theories don't have inputs. RCF is a countable set of sentences in the language of ordered rings. RCF certainly has uncountable models, like $\mathbb{R}$, but it can't define every element of every model. In any case, I've added an answer below - I hope it helps.

Comment: @AlexKruckman In above you mentioned "See here for a discussion of whether mere equality of two real numbers is decidable".  I looked at the link, it seems when using binary expansion, the comparison of two real numbers can run forever, which says real number equality problem is undecidable. That makes sense.  <br/>  

On the other hand, RCF theory defines <= symbol, which implies equality too, because a<=b and b<=a means a=b.  As you said R is a model of RCF theory, then real number equality should be decidable.  Why do we have such contradiction? Anything missing?

Comment: When $T$ is a first-order theory, a model of $T$ is *any* set together with *any* set-theoretic interpretations of the relation and function symbols in the language such that the axioms are satisfied. There is no requirement about computability of this set or computability the relations and functions. "RCF is decidable" does not mean that every model is computable. There will always be wildly incomputable models of any theory with infinite models.

Comment: What "RCF is decidable" means is something syntactic: There is an algorithm which, given a *sentence* $\varphi$ in the language of RCF (with no free variables, and only using the symbols in the language), decides whether RCF proves $\varphi$. Now, as a consequence of the soundness and completeness theorem for first-order logic, RCF proves $\varphi$ if and only if $\varphi$ is true in every model of RCF. But there's a big difference between being told, for example, that the sentence $\forall x(x\geq 0\to \exists y\, y^2 = x)$ is true in every real closed field, vs. being able to computably ...

Comment: ... answer questions about specific real numbers in finite time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "any real number combined with arithmetic operations and equalities or inequalities are decidable". Do you mean "the set of all real numbers combined with ..."? The short answer is the theorem applies to any subset of real numbers that satisfies those axioms, but it's a much more general result.

Tarski's theorem has little to do with real numbers $\mathbb R$. It's a theorem about formal axiomatic systems, not sets or models.

It states that the first order theory of [real closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) is decidable. In other words, given any first order statement (roughly one that allows $\forall, \exists$ and field operations (functions) and order relations), it can be either proved or disproved from the axioms (1)(2)(3) you listed.

By Godel's completeness theorem, this means that every first order statement has the same truth value for all real closed fields. In particular, $\mathbb R$ itself is a real closed field, hence every 1st order statement has a truth value that can be decided from the axioms of (1)-(3) alone, no other fancy ZFC machinery is necessary. Also, all the real algebraic numbers form a real closed field $\mathbb R_{\mathrm{alg}}$, hence it also has decidable first order theory.

It's clear that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R_{\mathrm{alg}}$ are very different, but they can not be distinguished by any first order statement. For example, their cardinalities are different, $\mathbb R$ contains transcendental elements while $\mathbb R_{\mathrm{alg}}$ doesn't. Tarski's theorem implies that in particular cardinality and transcendental elements cannot be characterized by first order statements.

Comment: @Mike: I did not write this answer, I just fixed some minor typesetting issues. The field of real numbers is a model of RCF (the standard one, in fact), which this answer states explicitly in the third paragraph. Nothing in this answer has anything to do with uncountability of the reals, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Just As real numbers are uncountable, I guess you mean it’s not possible to use all real numbers as universe to construct a model for RCF theory, right? Then, why did Example 1F.14 in Page 29 in https://www.math.ucla.edu/~ynm/lectures/lnl.pdf describe a structure with R as universe to be a model for RCF?

Comment: @Mike May I ask why you think the cardinality matters? Both $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R_{\mathrm{alg}}$ are models for RCF theory. This is not a problem, because the FOL of RCF is incapable of discussing the cardinality (of the models). In fact, FOL was almost never able to determine the cardinalities of its models, whether the theory is complete (like RFC) or not (like PA or ZFC), according to the [Löwenheim–Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

I think there's some confusion here about what decidability of $\mathsf{RCF}$ means.

The theory of real closed fields, $\mathsf{RCF}$, is a theory in first-order logic in the language of ordered rings: $L_{\mathrm{OR}} = \{+,-,\times,0,1,\leq\}$. "$\mathsf{RCF}$ is decidable" means that there is an algorithm (a Turing machine, say) which takes as input an $L_{\mathrm{OR}}$-sentence and returns "yes" or "no" depending on whether $\mathsf{RCF}\vdash \varphi$.

Since $\mathsf{RCF} = \mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{R})$ (which follow from the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is a real closed field and $\mathsf{RCF}$ is complete), we can interpret a "yes" answer from this algorithm as meaning $\mathbb{R}\models \varphi$ and a "no" answer as meaning $\mathbb{R}\models \lnot \varphi$.

But please note that $L_{\mathrm{OR}}$ cannot talk directly about arbitrary real numbers. Each natural number can be represented by a term of the form $1+1+\dots+1$, but there is no obvious way for $L_{\mathrm{OR}}$ to make statements about $\pi$, for example. Indeed, since there are only finitely many symbols in $L_{\mathrm{OR}}$, there are only countably many $L_{\mathrm{OR}}$-sentences. [And this should not be surprising: countability is necessary to even talk about decidability in the usual sense, since a Turing machine can only accept countably many possible inputs.]

---

However, there is a sense in which the decidability result for $\mathsf{RCF}$ applies to statements about *certain* real numbers. Say a real number $r$ is *definable* if there is an $L_{\mathrm{OR}}$-formula $\varphi_r(x)$ in one free variable, such that for all $s\in \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}\models \varphi_r(s)$ if and only if $s = r$. If $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is an $L_{\mathrm{OR}}$-formula with $n$ free variables and $r_1,\dots,r_n$ are definable real numbers, with $r_i$ defined by $\varphi_{r_i}$, then we have $\mathbb{R}\models \varphi(r_1,\dots,r_n)$ if and only if $$\mathbb{R}\models \exists x_1\dots\exists x_n\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \varphi_{r_i}(x_i)\land \psi(x_1,\dots,x_n)\right).$$ So we can decide whether $\mathbb{R}\models \varphi(r_1,\dots,r_n)$ by applying the decision algorithm for $\mathsf{RCF}$ to the sentence above.

It turns out that the definable real numbers are exactly the real algebraic numbers, i.e., those real numbers which are roots to some non-zero polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. This is a countable real closed subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, the real closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. So it would be reasonable to say that the decision procedure for $\mathsf{RCF}$ applies to $L_{\mathrm{OR}}$-sentences with parameters from the field of real algebraic numbers.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like you gave a language that can express FOL sentences with real algebraic numbers (with addition, subtraction, multiplication and <=) that can be decided using RCF's decision procedure.  Right?  


In addition, that also means the following structure can be a model for RCF Theory: 

1.universe is all real algebraic numbers, 
2. Functions: arithmetic functions (of addition, subtraction, multiplication, why no division which should be implied by multiplication except dividing by 0 should be excluded in some way?) 
3.Relations: <=


.Right?

Comment: BTW, in the structure above, for real algebraic number, is RCF’s Axiom 3 still needed as additional restrictions, or the set of all real algebraic number already automatically satisfies this axiom?  By Axiom 3, I mean: for every odd number d, the axiom asserting that all polynomials of degree d have at least one root.

Comment: @Mike (1) Yes, it's a standard and easy fact that the field of real algebraic numbers is a real closed field. In particular, every odd degree polynomial with coefficients in the real algebraic numbers has a root in the real algebraic numbers. (2) We typically don't include division in the language when talking about fields from the point of view of model theory, because function symbols are supposed to be total, and we can't divide by $0$.

Comment: Perhaps I am not remembering things correctly, but I think RCF also has effective quantifier elimination, which should mean that we also have a decision procedure for any effective RCF (i.e. a RCF for which we have effective addition, multiplication and comparison). Perhaps this is even true for any (effective) o-minimal expansion of a group. I did not think about it too hard though, so maybe this does not make sense. Also, I wouldn't be completely surprised to learn that there are no other effective RCFs.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks. BTW, is there an RCF model with a bigger real number set than algebraic ? As real numbers are uncountable, I guess it’s not possible to use all real numbers as universe to construct a model for RCF theory, right? Then, why did Example 1F.14 in Page 29 in https://www.math.ucla.edu/~ynm/lectures/lnl.pdf describe a structure with R as universe to be a model for RCF?

Comment: @tomasz Yes, that's a really good point. I suspect that the real closure of the subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by finitely many computable real numbers will be computable...

Comment: @Mike There is no requirement that models have to be countable. $\mathbb{R}$ is certainly a model of RCF, and in fact *any* ordered field has a real closure which is a model of RCF.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Is “for every odd number d, the axiom asserting that all polynomials of degree d have at least one root” (one of the axioms in RCF theory) always true with real number set R ?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Previously you mentioned “RCF is a countable set of sentences in the language of ordered rings. RCF certainly has uncountable models, like R”. Is it because RCF only defines two constant symbols (0 and 1), and with arithmetic operations applied on these two constants and countable number of variables with FOL logical connectives and equality symbols (again countable), the outcome sentences (combinations of these) are countable?  In another word, countability of this set of sentences (i.e. RCF theory) has nothing to do with countability of its model’s universe?